# I am trying to minimize the size of js file using JS Minifier but that JS minifier throw a error as "Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

> I want to compress My JS code using JS Minifier,but when i am trying to compress the code it throws the error as "unexpected token".I am using "SPCK code editor" in that the whole code working nicely.

**Code to Compress Is Here**

```
let makeReverse = document.querySelector('#makeReverse');
let makeReverse1 = makeReverse.addEventListener('click', reverseTheNumber);

function reverseTheNumber() {

  let getInput = document.querySelector('#inputValue');
  const numToSeperate = getInput.value;
  const arrayOfDigits = Array.from(String(numToSeperate));
  let reverse = arrayOfDigits.reverse();
  let reverseString = reverse.toString();

  let output = reverseString.replace(/,/g, '');
  document.querySelector('#output').innerText = output;
};
```

**Giving The error as**
[image: Here I Have Wriiten Function at last and called Earlier(Code Is Same As Above Mentioned]

[image: Here I Have Written Function earlier and Called last(Code Is Same As Above Mentioned)]

■ Whole Html css js code here...
https://codepen.io/adi45code/pen/oNLRJWE

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem... but `let makeReverse1 = makeReverse.addEventListener('click', reverseTheNumber);` should be just `makeReverse.addEventListener('click', reverseTheNumber);`... You don't save an event listener to a variable. At least not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I also use that ,but the error is giving...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the es6 syntax isn't supported by [jscompress](https://jscompress.com) without `babel-minify` enabled.

[image]

Make sure that you check `ECMAScript 2020 (via babel-minify)`.